# Can any conditional operators be used with an element while defining a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, array, coding-standards, if

While building a multi-dimensional array as shown below, I need to use a loop to retrieve some value from `$this_fulfillment_record` to be assigned to `"amount" =>`. Can a if statement be used while defining the array `"[trackingInfo]" => array(` If so, please show me an example.

```
    // Array to be built to match JSON structure.
    $fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'] = [];

    foreach ($fulfillment_records as $this_fulfillment_record) {
        // Assemble the fulfillment array for Walmart.
        $fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'][] = array
        [trackingInfo] => Array(                                                                    
                           [shipDateTime] => 1580821866000
                           [carrierName] => Array(
   
                                               otherCarrier] => 
                                                [carrier] => FedeX
                                            )
                                        [methodCode] => Standard
                                        [trackingNumber] => 22344
                                        // Can if statment be used like this?
                                        if ($this_fulfillment_record['carrier'] == "FedeX") {
                                            [trackingURL] => http://walmart/tracking/ups?&type=MP&seller_id=12345&promise_date=03/02/2020&dzip=92840&tracking_numbers=92345
                                        } else {
                                            [trackingURL] => =""
                                        }
                                        
                            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function/method or an array_map to define the content on an attribute. For example:

```
// Array to be built to match JSON structure.
$amount_values = [1, 2, 3]; // some sample amount values to interact 
$fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'] = [];

foreach ($fulfillment_records as $this_fulfillment_record) {
    // Assemble the fulfillment array for Walmart.
    $fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'][] = array(
        "status" => "Shipped",
        "statusQuantity" => array(
            "unitOfMeasurement" => "Each",
            // interact with some other value
            "amount" => array_map(
                function(value) {
                    // do your logic/interaction here as a normal method to prepare the content to be set
                    return value_to_be_set; 
                },
                $amount_values
            )
        )
    );
```

Or, you can use an anonymous function If you need to process an return a content that is very specific:

```
// Array to be built to match JSON structure.
$interactor = function($yourParameter) {
    // do your code interaction here
    return $value_to_be_returned;
};

$fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'] = [];

foreach ($fulfillment_records as $this_fulfillment_record) {
    // Assemble the fulfillment array for Walmart.
    $fulfillment_array['orderShipment']['orderLines']['orderLine'][] = array(
        "status" => "Shipped",
        "statusQuantity" => array(
            "unitOfMeasurement" => "Each",
            // interact with some other value
            "amount" => $interactor($someObjectToInteract)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Marcel, I wonder if "if statement" is possible to use around the element ""amount" =>".

Comment: You cannot use around the "amount" key, but you can try to create an interaction (with array_map or anonymous function) to generate the correct array for the "statusQuantity", and then, you can generate the correct content (with or without the "amount" key)